# how to delete records from DB with update cascade in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to delete records from DB (MySQL) with update cascade.

There is a day plan and some duration plans associated with this day plan on DB. I want to update the duration list for this day plan.

- When I update the day plan with the duration list that has new or updated duration plans, it works properly and I see these update records on DB.
- However, when I update the day plan with duration list that some duration plans are missing (deleted), nothing happens. I hope that missing duration plans would be deleted.

Example;

- duration plans associated with the day plan on DB; a, b, c.
- I update the day plan with the list that has a(updated), b(no updated).
- I can see on DB that 
    -> 'a' is updated.
    -> 'b' is no updated.
    -> *** 'c' is NOT DELETED! (How can I delete this 'c' with this update cascade!)

Initializations;

```
...
    DayPlan dayPlan = new DayPlan();
    Set<DurationPlan> list = new HashSet<DurationPlan>();
...
```

Preperations to update;

```
...
    durationPlan = new DurationPlan(dayPlan, x, y, z);
    list.add(durationPlan);
    dayPlan.setDURATION_PLANS(list);
...
```

Update process with Hibernate-session;

```
...
session.saveOrUpdate(dayPlan);
...
```

DurationPlan hibernate-mapping;

```
<class name="planManagement.DurationPlan" table="DURATIONPLAN">
    <id name="DURATION_PLAN_ID" type="int">
        <column name="DURATION_PLAN_ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="DAY_PLAN" class="planManagement.DayPlan" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <column name="DAY_PLAN_ID" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    ...
</class>
```

DayPlan hibernate-mapping;

```
<class name="planManagement.DayPlan" table="DAYPLAN">
    <id name="DAY_PLAN_ID" type="int">
        <column name="DAY_PLAN_ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <set name="DURATION_PLANS" table="DURATIONPLAN" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="DAY_PLAN_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="planManagement.DurationPlan" />
    </set>
    ...
</class>
```

All feedback appreciated!

Comment: Does this silence mean that there is no way to delete records with update cascade ?? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, How hibernate will find which records need to be deleted? As when you call `session.saveOrUpdate(dayPlan);` where `dayPlan` will contains list of `duration` containing only two objects i.e a,b (a(updated), b(no updated).) As per you 'c' need to be deleted but how hibernate will get to know 'c' need to be deleted.

Comment: Does it mean that update cascade cannot be used to delete duration plans associated with the day plan?

Comment: @séan35, I don't think its possible.